# How to find axes by YLabel string?

Tags: matlab

I am creating a figure with multiple subplots and saving it to a file. like this:

```
fig = figure;
ax1 = subplot(2, 1, 1);
ax2 = subplot(2, 1, 2);
ylabel(ax1, 'First');
ylabel(ax2, 'Second');
savefig('myfigure.fig')
```

Later, I want to copy one of the subplots to a new figure without re-running the code that creates the figure. My current approach is to load the saved figure, locate the axes I want to copy by its YLabel, and then copying it to a new figure:

```
newfig = figure;
oldfig = openfig('myfigure.fig');
ylabel_obj = findobj(oldfig, 'String', 'First');  % This is not givng me what I expect
old_axes_obj = ylabel_obj.Parent;
new_axes_obj = copyobj(old_axes_obj, newfig);
```

The problem is that `findobj` above is not finding the YLabel. It just returns a 0x0 empty GraphicsPlaceholder array. Why isn't `findobj` finding my YLabel? Is there a better way to find the axes I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [handle visibility](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.text-properties.html#budt_bq-1_sep_shared-HandleVisibility) for the label text object is turned off, so it will not show up in the `Children` property of its parent axes, and therefore won't be found when using [`findobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html). You can instead use [`findall`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findall.html) to get around this limitation:

```
ylabel_obj = findall(oldfig, 'String', 'First');
```

Alternatively, you can set the [root `ShowHiddenHandles` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.root-properties.html#buc8_0n-ShowHiddenHandles) to `'on'` to list all object handles regardless of their `HandleVisibility` property setting, making `findobj` and `findall` equivalent.